# Как сделать так, чтобы при возврате страницы назад option снова становился Выберите поиск

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Как сделать так, чтобы при возврате страницы назад `option` снова становился "Выберите поиск"? Ничего не получается.

```
<select onchange="window.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <option value="">Выберите поиск</option>
    <option value="http://yandex.ru">Яндекс</option>
    <option value="http://google.com">Гугл</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте посредством JavaScript сбросить значение:

```js
document.getElementById("category").selectedIndex = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < selectTags.length; i++) {
  selectTags[i].selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

```html
<select id="category" onchange="window.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
  <option value="">Выберите поиск</option>
  <option value="http://yandex.ru">Яндекс</option>
  <option value="http://google.com">Гугл</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53898/discussion-on-answer-by-arsen--------).